# Can't Upgrade Centos to 5.6 / Dependency Errors

Tags: centos

Tried these steps:
http://www.how2centos.com/upgrading-centos-5-5-to-centos-5-6/

When I run yum update, I get the below

http://tinypaste.com/c8d9b2

Its not really 5.6, because I was originally on 4.8, then 5.3 and now these errors (even though it shows 5.6)

root@server [~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 5.6 (Final)

root@server [~]# uname -a
Linux server.domain.com 2.6.9-89.0.19.ELsmp #1 SMP Fri Jan 8 06:32:22 EST 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

The link worked for me.

You don't provide the full output but one problem is that something is going wrong with the openssl package (which provides libcrypto.so.6). Look through the full output of yum update for mentions on openssl. What is the output of `rpm -q -i openssl.x86_64` (assuming you are using the x86_64 architecture).

The guide recommends running `yum update` but it is better to use `yum upgrade` so that obsolete packages are handled.

Comment: http://tinypaste.com/dbec7

Please see that link. I really need help here

Comment: http://tinypaste.com/dbec7 Please see that link